# PHP Docker image built in Atlassian Bamboo has permission errors

Tags: php, apache, docker, dockerfile, bamboo

I have a build plan in Atlassian Bamboo that builds a Docker image of a PHP project. The image includes Apache2, PHP and dependencies, and of course the project itself. When I try to run the Docker image generated by this build plan, I get a permission denied error to the project.

I am using `root` as the primary user in the Docker container. I also tried to include a `chown` command in the Dockerfile for www-data:www-data for the PHP project directory but the problem did not go away.

[image: Permission denied error]

This is what happens to the permission of the indicated file:

```
--w-------  1 root     root      582 Feb 18 12:17 index.php
```

The contents of the Dockerfile

```
FROM php:apache

RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Manila /etc/localtime \
    && apt-get install -y libzip-dev libpng-dev unzip git tzdata libpq-dev && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql pgsql zip gd \ 
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY composer.json .
COPY composer.lock .
COPY composer.phar .

RUN php composer.phar install

RUN chmod 775 -R /var/www/html

COPY . .
```

Comment: Can you show us the exact errors you're getting?

Comment: Added an image.

Comment: It really helps if you just paste it as text. That makes it searchable, and a lot easier for many to read.

Comment: That's a file missing error. Are you sure that file exists? What permissions does it have?

Comment: Do you happen to build the conf files with Kangaroo or Shamp? If yes, under what user (Sudo or otherwise) you do it?
Also, does the image use mod php? It looks as if your issue is in the conf file, it tries to include something it should not.

Comment: No, I'm not using either Kangaroo or Shamp.

Comment: @tadman, the file permissions are messed up as seen in the description above. Now I'm wondering why this is so. The only difference is the fact that it's Bamboo that's building it. Another strange thing is that this is not consistent behaviour.

Comment: That's a very odd way to permission the file. Write only? Can't read? Something's wrong there. Normally you'd expect `rw` for `root` at the very least, or in some cases `r` for read-only. `w` is basically "can only append data, cannot read" as in a dead-drop file.

Comment: I added the Dockerfile as a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this [post](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/Permissions-trouble/qaq-p/930046) indicating that the problem was an internal change in Atlassian Bamboo. What I did then was to use `771` as the permission for all the files in the PHP project and changed the ownership as well through `chown`. This combination was the correct one apparently and allowed the application to run.